# Cant access a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an `undefined` when I try the post to twitter function. Should the `quote_text` variable be global and therefore accessible by the `quoteTwitter` function?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  loadJSON();
  getQuote();
  console.log(quote_text);
});

// Declare variables
var json_obj;
var num = 0;
var quote_text = "";

// Display a quote - this method is not perfect since the random number will repeat itself and it appears as if no new quote is delivered
function getQuote(callback) {
  var html = "";
  num = randNum();
  quote_text = json_obj[num].quote;

  html += "<strong> " + quote_text + " </strong>";

  $("#quote").html(html);
  $("#author").html(json_obj[num].author);
};

// Post the current quote on twitter
function quoteTwitter(quote_text){
  var tweet = quote_text;
  window.open('https://twitter.com/home?status=' +encodeURIComponent(tweet),"_blank"); 
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `quoteTwitter`?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools: Set breakpoints, step through the code and inspect variables.

Comment: I call it on the anchor tag in the html with href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function definition includes `quote_text` as a parameter, so inside the function it's trying to use that instead of the global variable with the same name.  You're presumably not passing anything to the function when you call it, so it comes out as undefined.

You can fix this by changing this:

```
function quoteTwitter(quote_text){
```

to this:

```
function quoteTwitter(){
```

...but it'd probably be better in the long run to pass the correct value in as a parameter, if possible, instead of depending on global variables.